# $V= - \int_{\frac 1 3}^{\frac 1 2} \dfrac {\ln v}{1 - v^2} dv, X= \int_{\frac 1 2 \ln 2}^{\frac 1 2 \ln 3} \ln (\coth x) dx$ . Show they are equal

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

> The definite integrals V and X are defined by
>   $$V= - \int_{\frac 1 3}^{\frac 1 2} \dfrac {\ln v}{1 - v^2} \,\text{d}v$$
>   $$X= \int_{\frac 1 2 \ln 2}^{\frac 1 2 \ln 3} \ln (\coth x) \,\text{d}x$$
>   Show, without evaluating any of them, that they are equal.

Starting from V we intend to reach X.
Let $v = \coth x$
Then $\dfrac {\text{d}v}{\text{d}x} = 1-\coth^2 x$

So it gives $\ln(\coth x)$.

Also, looking at the limit,
$v = \dfrac {e^{2x} + 1}{e^{2x} -1}$
$\implies 2x = \ln \left|\dfrac {1+v}{v-1}\right|$

Where $\frac 1 2$ gives $\frac 1 2 \ln 3$
and likewise $\frac 1 3$ gives $\frac 1 2 \ln 2$.

I don't see why you need $-$ on the R.H.S of V.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your working is that from
$$v = \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}$$
we do not get that
$$2x = \ln\left|\frac{1+v}{v-1}\right|$$
but actually get
$$2x = \ln\frac{1+v}{v-1}$$
(without the absolute value bars)

The values $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ are not in the range of the $\coth$ function, and so the substitution which you made is not valid.

We can, however, transform the original integral into one where we can make the substitution which you did. First, use the substitution $u = v^{-1}$. You will see that your original integral then becomes
$$V = \int_3^2 \frac{\ln u}{1-u^2}\,\text{d}u$$
(where the $V$ does include the minus sign!)

You can then make the substitution $x = \coth u$ like you did, and you will get
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}\ln 2}^{\frac{1}{2}\ln 3} \ln(\coth x)\,\text{d} x$$

Comment: I always thought taking $log$ both sides gives you modulus.. Maybe only in integration. Thank you